# Is it reproducible to use Arbitrary.sample from within an Action?

Tags: java, property-based-testing, jqwik

We have a stateful test for an order system. There is an `Arbitrary` that will generate an `Order` object that has a number of `LineItem`'s.

There are actions to:

- Create an `Order`
- Cancel a `LineItem`

The action to create an order takes the order itself, eg:

```
Arbitraries.defaultFor(Order.class).map(CreateOrderAction::new)
```

The state for the actions has knowledge about all created orders.

To cancel a `LineItem`, we need knowledge about what orders are created. Inside `CancelLineItemAction` is it safe to do the following?

```
LineItem line = Arbitraries.<Collection<Order>>of(state.orders())
                           .flatMap(order -> Arbitraries.<Collection<LineItem>>of(order.lineItems()))
                           .sample();
```

Based on the javadoc of `Arbitrary.sample()`, it *seems* safe, but this construct isn't explicitly mentioned in the documentation on stateful tests, and we don't want to use it extensively only to break the reproducibility of our tests.

Comment: The sample() method is not designed to be used that way. Since jqwik will remove and reorder actions during shrinking of action sequences your approach will (sometimes) lead to non-deterministic behaviour. I‘ll sketch out the different options I see in an answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TLDR

- `Arbitrary.sample()` is not designed to be used in that way
- I recommend to use a random cancel index with modulo over the number of line items

### 1. Why Arbitrary.sample() is not recommended

`Arbitrary.sample()` is designed to be used outside of properties, e.g. to experiment with generated values or to use it in other contexts like JUnit Jupiter. There are at least three reasons:

- The underlying random seed used for generating values depends on what happens
  before sampling. Thus the results are not really reproducible.
- Sampling will not consider any added domain contexts that may change what's
  being generated.
- Values generated by `sample()` DO NOT PARTICIPATE IN SHRINKING

### 2. Option 1: Hand in a Random object and use it for generating

Hand in a Random instance when generating a CancelLineItemAction:

```
Arbitraries.random().map(random -> new CancelLineItemAction(random))
```

Use the random to invoke a generator:

```
LineItem line = Arbitraries.of(state.orders())
           .flatMap(order -> Arbitraries.of(order.lineItems()))
           .generator(100).next(random).value();
```

But actually that's very involved for what you want to do. Here's a simplification:

### 3. Option 2: Hand in a Random object and use it for picking a line item

Same as above but don't take a detour with sampling:

```
List<LineItem> lineItems = state.orders().stream()
                                .flatMap(order -> order.lineItems().stream())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());

int randomIndex = random.nextInt(lineItems.size());
LineItem line = lineItems.get(randomIndex);
```

Both option 1 and 2 will (hopefully) behave reasonably in jqwik's lifecycle
but they won't attempt any shrinking. That's why I recommend the next option.

### 4. Option 3: Hand in a cancel index and modulo it over the number of line items

To generate the action:

```
Arbitraries.integer().between(0, MAX_LINE_ITEMS)
                     .map(cancelIndex -> new CancelLineItemAction(cancelIndex))
```

Use it in action:

```
List<LineItem> lineItems = state.orders().stream()
                                .flatMap(order -> order.lineItems().stream())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());

int randomIndex = cancelIndex % lineItems.size();
LineItem line = lineItems.get(randomIndex);
```

The approach is described in more detail here: https://blog.johanneslink.net/2020/03/11/model-based-testing/

### 5. Future Outlook

In some more or less distant future jqwik may allow to hand in the current state when generating actions. This would make stuff like yours a bit simpler. But this feature has not yet been prioritized.

Comment: Thanks! I had missed following all of the links in the blog post.